Error :- InvocationTargetException , FileNotFoundException: contents.json, Fragment, Kotlin
I got These Errors
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mykotlinapp, PID: 19988
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:558)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957) 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: contents.json


Hi, I am trying to create a story Book app with Kotlin but I am beginner and learning programing. and I try to create this app with local Json file (loadJsonFromAssets) with glide, in home fragment, but I got this error, I don't know how to fix it, please help me to fix it.
Home Fragment Code
    private lateinit var bookAdapter: BookAdapter
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var dataList: ArrayList<BooksData>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)


        // Initialize the RecyclerView
        dataList = ArrayList()
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.bookRecyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
        bookAdapter = BookAdapter(this@HomeFragment, dataList)
        recyclerView.adapter = bookAdapter
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)


        loadData()
       // loadJson()
        return view
    }

    private fun loadData() {
        val jsonString = loadJson("contents.json")
        val items = parseJson(jsonString)
        bookAdapter.setData(items)

    }

    private fun loadJson(contents: String): String {
        val inputStream = this.requireContext().assets.open(contents)
        val size = inputStream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        inputStream.read(buffer)
        inputStream.close()
        return String(buffer)
    }


    private fun parseJson(jsonString: String): ArrayList<BooksData> {

        val dataList = ArrayList<BooksData>()
        val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonString)
        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
            val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
            val bookName = jsonObject.getString("bookName")
            val imageUrl = jsonObject.getString("imageUrl")
            dataList.add(BooksData(imageUrl, bookName))

        }; return dataList
    }

}

data class
data class BooksData(val bookName:String, val imageUrl:String){
}



Adapter class
class BookAdapter(var context: HomeFragment, private var dataList: ArrayList<BooksData>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.BookViewHolder>() {

    inner class BookViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var bookNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookName)
        var bookImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageUrl)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BookViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.book_category_item, parent, false)
        return BookViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataList.size
    fun setData(data: ArrayList<BooksData>) {
        dataList.clear()
        dataList.addAll(data)
        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BookViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataList[position]
        holder.bookNameTextView.text = item.bookName
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(item.imageUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .error(R.drawable.vec_quiz)
            .into(holder.bookImageView)
    }


}



Json file
{
  "items": [
    {
      "bookName": "Basic Grammar",
      "imageUrl": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1_eVoTO4IeTW1gAbNBb_0-GWASecBNGgS"

    } ,
    {
      "bookName": "Basic Grammar",
      "imageUrl": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1_eVoTO4IeTW1gAbNBb_0-GWASecBNGgS"

    }

  ]
}


Please Help me to fix this error, thanks

Try adding a leading slash: loadJson("/contents.json")

Yes, You are right  "json/content/contents.json"
